# insert spreadsheet table into msword content control block using open xml

Tags: openxml

i got table object from excel sheet now i want to insert that table into microsoft word content control block by programatically.

i can add any text into content control block but not able to insert spreadsheet table

Note: i want keep same format which having in excel table and don't want iterate through excel table rows and all rows operations

how can achieve this?

any help would be appreciated, thanks